# Comparing Date in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, date

I have a date field in my mongoDB and I want to find the number of entries from start date to end date. Date is in "2014-03-19 22:48:00" format.

I have tries the following queries by they are not showing any results.

```
`db.user_tracking.find({date:{$gte:ISODate("2013-10-02T00:00:00Z"), $lt:ISODate("2013-12-02T00:00:00Z")}})

db.user_tracking.find({date:{$gte:ISODate("2014-1-02T00:00:00Z"), $lt:ISODate("2014-9-02T00:00:00Z")}})

db.user_tracking.find({date:{$gte:ISODate("2014-01-02T00:00:00Z"), $lt:ISODate("2014-09-02T00:00:00Z")}})

db.user_tracking.find({date:{$gte:ISODate("2014-01-02T00:00:00Z"), $lt:ISODate("2014-09-22T00:00:00Z")}})

db.user.find({date:new Date("2014-03-19")}) 

db.user.find({date:new Date("2014-03-19 22:48:00")})

db.user.find({date:"2014-03-19 22:48:00"})`
```

I am sure there is some data in those dates as i have same database in mySQL which is showing my correct results.

I am using mongo version 2.4.9

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format your code properly.

Comment: Why is the MySQL tag here?

Comment: You are inserting data into mongodb using java ?

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis: No, where did you got that from? I am not inserting anything. i want to retrieve data based on particular dates. I am using meteorJS

Comment: Sorry.but  Mongo db store date it in utc format.plz try using utc date time

Comment: it is showing date in this format "2014-03-19 22:48:00"

Comment: Please show us a sample document from your MongoDB collection with a `date` field.